# What are the loops by delooping a group to a groupoid?

Tags: terminology, intuition, higher-category-theory

I'm trying to understand the definition of [delooping a group to a groupoid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/delooping#delooping_of_a_group_to_a_groupoid), but I don't see the loops in a group that aren't present in the groupoid. Then why is it called delooping?

Comment: It's called delooping because it's the right inverse of the loop functor

Comment: @user40276 This sounds good. But what kind of animal is the loop functor? And what kind of loops are created by it?

Comment: The loop functor picks a pointed topological space and gives you the loop space at that point. In the case of a group, you should consider the group as a discrete space pointed at the identity. You can also restate this in terms of simplicial objects and, in this case, the group is simply a set viewed as a simplicial object.

Comment: @user40276 Could you please give a reference for this?

Comment: You can find references in the bottom of the page that you cited. If you're having difficulties with this , maybe you should focus on understanding the basics of algebraic topology and category theory first.